# Price formatting for Portuguese

Tags: php

On my website, `echo $symbols['currency']; echo $fields['price'];` holds a value in US currency format and it outputs R$19800

and `echo $symbols['currency']; echo number_format($fields['price']);` outputs R$19,800

How do I format it to output **R$19.800,00** which is Portuguese price formatting?

I tried

```
echo $symbols['currency'];
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');
echo money_format('%.2n', $fields['price']);
```

and it outputs **R$EUR 19.800,00** which is corrent, but Im finding it hard to remove EUR from printing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: why do you put an italian locale to output something in portuguese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the PHP function [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$money =  money_format('%.2n', $fields['price']);
echo str_replace("EUR", "", $money);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without locale and `str_replace()` (which I consider just fixing/hiding something done not correctly) by just using `number_format()`:

```
echo $symbols['currency'];
echo number_format((float) $fields['price'], 2, ',', '.');
```